# Why constructors generated by using declarations have the same access levels of the base classes'?

Tags: c++, c++14

It's easier to explain it in code:

```
   class A {
    protected:
        A(int i) {}
        void foo() {}
    };

    class B : public A {
    public:
        B() : A(0) {}
        using A::A;
        using A::foo;
    };

    int main() 
    {
        B b1;
        // [protected] A::foo => [public] B::foo
        b1.foo(); // Ok
        // [protected] A::A(int) => [protected] B::B(int)
        B b2(0); // cannot access protected member
    }
```

I tried the code in VS2015. I could change the access levels of member functions with using declarations, while I couldn't do the same on constructors. That's weird to me. Does anyone have an idea why they design it works like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructors are not generated in this case, instead they are inherited (actually from a base class).
According with the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration), when inheriting a constructor:

> It has the same access as the corresponding base constructor

Where *access* indicates [access specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access).
On the other side, for member methods:

> Using-declaration introduces a member of a base class into the derived class definition, such as to expose a protected member of base as public member of derived.

In this case, access can be explicitly changed.

That's why *you can change the access levels of member functions with using declarations, while you cannot do the same on constructors*.

Comment: I still don't know why they design it in that way, but thanks for the information. I mean, I still can change the access levels by defining constructors in the levels I want in derived classes. Keeping inheriting constructors the same access levels as bases' just makes it less useful.